# Joint world pose for each step of simulation

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

How would I obtain joint world pose data for each step in a simulation? I have a model plugin that can get the joint position *before* the simulation is run, but how do I get the joint world pose for each simulation step?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20237/joint-world-pose-for-each-step-of-simulation/) by [jc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6174/jc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

If you have a function that gets the joint world pose before simulation i assume you are calling it in the Load() function of the plugin. You can then, in the same way, call your function in the OnUpdate() loop. By my understanding, that gets called every iteration.

You can find a more detailed description at:
[Sensor OnUpdate](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contact_sensor)

---

Originally posted by [Veztak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5931/veztak/) with karma: 36 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jc](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6174/jc/) on 2018-08-14**:
Thanks for the help! Outside of the tutorials where is this documented?